# Captcha image shown as strange symbols in Firefox

Tags: firefox, jsp, cross-browser, captcha

I am using [this](http://codepaste.net/s3rmzt) captcha code in a jsp. I call the jsp by the following code using iframe:

```
 <iframe id="captchaframe"  align="center" name="captchaframe" src="captcha.jsp" width="120" height="40" scrolling="no"
      frameborder="0" marginheight="-10" marginwidth="-10"/></iframe>
```

With explorer everything works pretty as in this picture:

[image]

But in Firefox the characters become something else entirely like in this picture:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Firefox doesn't recognise the output of your jsp file as image. Did you set mime content-type to image?

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html

Comment: Thanks, setting content type to image/jpeg fixed my problem.